# Extracting lines and field-based parts of lines from a file using regular expressions

Tags: regex, powershell, text-parsing

```
-CASServer V2.00 connection from 127.0.0.1 [] Diag mode only
Clients: Static 0/50  Dynamic 17/50
Sampler: 1 0x1074bd8 hSock(0x2d0)
Archiver: 0 0
OK    
0x1078b08:0x2fc  192.168.2.182  WorkStation84021  Dynamic  07:55:25 07/20/17    
0x1076d78:0x370  192.168.6.158  WorkStation84144  Dynamic  08:19:29 07/20/17    
0x1076f28:0x38c  192.168.3.75  WorkStation21590  Dynamic  08:27:56 07/20/17    
0x1089a98:0x394  192.168.12.147  WorkStation93778  Dynamic  08:29:50 07/20/17    
0x1089d68:0x378  192.168.2.200  WorkStation53283  Dynamic  08:34:03 07/20/17    
0x108a038:0x2d8  192.168.4.145  WorkStation38642  Dynamic  08:35:19 07/20/17    
0x108a308:0x35c  192.168.5.103  WorkStation35979  Dynamic  08:44:24 07/20/17    
0x108be80:0x37c  192.168.6.155  WorkStation53023  Dynamic  08:49:48 07/20/17    
0x107b7f8:0x360  192.168.5.104  WorkStation53269  Dynamic  08:50:45 07/20/17    
0x107bac8:0x384  192.168.2.244  WorkStation53297  Dynamic  08:51:53 07/20/17    
0x107bd98:0x36c  192.168.4.157  WorkStation53239  Dynamic  08:54:01 07/20/17    
0x107c230:0x3a4  192.168.5.7  WorkStation53229  Dynamic  08:59:29 07/20/17    
0x107c7e0:0x3ac  192.168.12.146  WorkStation93784  Dynamic  08:59:31 07/20/17    
0x107ce60:0x3b0  192.168.4.173  WorkStation53179  Dynamic  09:01:12 07/20/17    
0x107c710:0x3b4  192.168.2.175  WorkStation53047  Dynamic  09:02:06 07/20/17    
0x107cf30:0x368  192.168.5.85  SERVER53116  Dynamic  09:05:14 07/20/17    
0x107c3d0:0x3a8  192.168.5.126  WorkStation53279  Dynamic  09:06:36 07/20/17    
OK    
Unknown DIAG command    
OK
```

---

I need help with parsing this text file. I want to get the 2nd line "Dynamic #/50" and would like to extract that.

I also want to know if there is a Workstation name begins with SERVER
If one is found then I want to extract the IP, Workstation name and the time/date.

I am not sure what the best approach to solve this is.
I know that my file won't get very large (maximum # of lines is approximately 70 lines). For some reason, my Telnet output is adding blank lines between each statement

Comment: Could you tell us how the output is being generated? Is this the result of another PowerShell script that we can work with or is this the raw contents of a file or raw command output that you want to parse?

Comment: On top of what Ty asked for....Have you done any looking as to how to parse this file yourself? It would be better to see your approach so we can show you where you went wrong and help you improve it.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and with what results?

Answer (score 0):

The **most convenient (albeit slow) approach to extracting *full* lines** is to use **`Select-String`**:

```
> (Get-Content file | Select-String -List '\bDynamic \d+/50\b').Line
Clients: Static 0/50  Dynamic 17/50
```

While **`Select-String` accepts *multiple* regexes and you can even extract the matching part only / capture groups only from the `.Matches` property of the `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]` instances that `Select-String` property outputs**, your complex extraction needs make `Select-String` impractical.

Therefore, **custom logic** is required:

Note: The following solution **reads the input file into memory *as a whole***, which is **feasible with *small* input files** like yours; **for *larger* files (or for processing *command output*), use a pipeline-based solution with `ForEach-Object`**, which will be slower, but memory-efficient - see bottom:

```
# Read the entire file into an array of strings (line by line).
$lines = Get-Content file

# Extract the "Dynamic #/50" line
$lines -match '\bDynamic \d+/50\b'  # an array-valued LHS makes -match act as a filter

# Extract the server information.
foreach ($line in $lines) {
  $fields = -split $line  # split the line Awk-style into whitespace-separated fiels
  if ($fields[2] -match '^Server') { # check if 2nd fields starts with 'Server'
    $fields[1, 2, 4, 5] -join ' ' # join the fields of interest with a space and output
  }
}
```

The above yields:

```
Clients: Static 0/50  Dynamic 17/50
192.168.5.85 SERVER53116 09:05:14 07/20/17
```

---

The **equivalent pipeline-based solution**:

Again, this will be **more memory-efficient, but slower**.
Performance issues aside, **pipeline-based solutions are often more concise and conceptually elegant**.

```
Get-Content file | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -match '\bDynamic \d+/50') {
    $_ # output line as is
  } elseif (($fields = -split $_) -and $fields[2] -match '^Server') {
    $fields[1, 2, 4, 5] -join ' ' # output fields of interest, joined with spaces
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the community with a script that someone else can learn from so I am reluctant to just post a completed answer for you. I will give you a top level assessment and if you post your script and still have a problem then I will assist you further.

Your file has 3 district content formats. Each will require a different approach to parse. We can call them the top, middle, and bottom and we can separate them by the 'Ok' text. We can also ignore the bottom content area as it does not contain any useful data for your requirement.

Start by getting the contents of the file:
`$rawContent = get-content "c:\temp\yourfile.txt"`

Now break the content up via the 'Ok' string:
`$contentAreas = ($rawContent -split "Ok")`

Now each content area can be worked with separately.
`$contentAreas[0]` Will output the top dataset
`$contentAreas[1]` will output the middle dataset

I would recommend you work with the middle area first as it is slightly easier. Here you could use a where clause to find the line that matches "*SERVER*". Then you can parse just that line for the values you want.

Next you can work with the top area. Here I recommend you use .Split() to break apart the content via whitespace (spaces, tabs, and new lines). Then you can use .IndexOf to find the field by name and work from there.

Again, if you post something that shows effort and gives me something to work with I will be happy to assist you further.